# Rhythmbox Plays Static

Tags: music, rhythmbox, pulseaudio, gstreamer

Rhythmbox works fine, but sometimes certain tracks won't be played; sometimes when certain tracks are played all I hear is static/cracking sound with basically no sound at all.

If I restart rhythmbox and play the same song/s again, they will play fine (No static).

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem on 9.10. I tried changing it to ALSA and OSS. But it didnt help. Now, I know you want to resolve the Rhythmbox problem, but as an aside, I recommend using a different player. I liked exaile, which has a very Amarok-ish flavour.

`sudo apt-get install exaile`

Sorry, couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's crossfading.

See if it's turned on in your preferences, I was having the exact same problem.

If it is turned on, turn it off and then restart Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 3):

I've logged a bug, it's seems the right thing to do, I've seen this issue around, if this bug affects anyone else, subscribe here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/666199

Answer (score 1):

It's distortion that's coming from the volume conrol in Rhythmbox. Turn down the volume in the application and you're good to go!